# JUnit - Tests pass but still 0% code coverage

Tags: java, junit, mockito

So I started writing Junit tests for our project and we are using Junit with Mockito. However, when I try to test the REST endpoint (implemented through Jersey), the test pass but I am still getting 0% coverage for that method

Here is the code

```
 @GET
@Path("/{workFlow}/{caseId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseObject caseManagementGet(@Context UriInfo context, @PathParam("workFlow") String workFlow,
        @PathParam("caseId") String caseId, @QueryParam("details") String details) throws ApiException {
    QueryParameters queryParameters = new QueryParameters();
    PathParameters pathParameters = new PathParameters();
    buildPathParameter(pathParameters, ParameterName.workflow, workFlow);
    buildPathParameter(pathParameters, ParameterName.id, caseId);

    buildQueryParameter(queryParameters, ParameterName.details, details);

    return invokeHandler(context.getPath(), workFlow, RETRIEVE_CASE_DETAIL_ACTION, HttpMethod.GET, pathParameters,
            queryParameters, null);
}

protected void buildPathParameter(PathParameters pathParameters, ParameterName name, Object value)
        throws ApiException {
    try {
        pathParameters.put(name, value);
        return;
    }
    catch (ParameterException e) {
        throw apiException(DXM_UNSUPPORTED_SERVICE_ERROR, e);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw apiException(DXM_GENERAL_ERROR, e);
    }
}
protected void buildQueryParameter(QueryParameters queryParameters, ParameterName name, Object value)
        throws ApiException {
    try {
        queryParameters.put(name, value);
        return;
    }
    catch (ParameterException e) {
        throw apiException(DXM_UNSUPPORTED_SERVICE_ERROR, e);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw apiException(DXM_GENERAL_ERROR, e);
    }
}
```

Here is the Junit Test

```html
 @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    CaseManagementResource caseManagementResource = new CaseManagementResource();

    @Mock
    RequestObject requestObject;

    @Mock
    ResponseObject responseObject;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    
    @Test
    public void testCaseManagementGet() throws ApiException, URISyntaxException {
        try{
            UriInfo uriInfo = Mockito.mock(UriInfo.class);
            Mockito.when(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath())
            .thenReturn(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/bbpro/rest/v1/get"));
            ResponseObject response = caseManagementResource.caseManagementGet(uriInfo, "bbc", "123123", "setup");
            Assert.assertNotNull(response);
        }catch(ApiException e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

I am passing mock values into the GET method and then just asserting not null.

Comment: for coverage like eclmma you need to use spy to partial mock the object not just mock the entire class.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have that line up in the declaration part. I edited the code to include that!

Comment: can you also try to spy the UriInfo class? that field is returning the uri from an actual value. UriInfo uriInfo = Mockito.spy(new UriInfo()); --if that is the class under you are covering. caseManagementResource only return the response but not all the method under it since you are trying to mock the uri.